# Регулярные выражения java, замена ФИО по шаблону

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо при совпадении шаблона Имя Фамилия Отчество (прим. Иванов Иван Иванович)

Преобразовывать в другой шаблон (Иванов И. И.)

был написан такой шаблон:

`name.replaceAll("[А-Яа-я]*\\s[А-Яа-я]*\\s[А-Яа-я]*", "[А-Яа-я]*\\s[А-Яа-я].\\s[А-Яа-я].")`

Но, почему то, не меняет строку

Хотя под первое регулярное выражение шаблон (Иванов Иван Иванович) подходит

Comment: у вас точно проходит по регулярному выражению?? Вы проверяли это в дебаге??

Comment: Результат кода в вопросе `"[А-Яа-я]*s[А-Яа-я].s[А-Яа-я]"`. Очевидно, автор имел ввиду, что по шаблону находит, но не работает замена. Я прав?

Comment: Да, именно так) Шаблон проходит, а замена нет)

Comment: Попробуйте переписать замену. После скобки укажите переменную name, но до пробела + первую букву после первого пробела + "." + первую букву после второго пробела + "."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Получилась такая регулярка:

```
String name = "Иванов Иван Иванович";

// Иванов Иван Иванович -> Иванов И. И.
name = name.replaceAll("([А-Яа-я]+) ([А-Я])[а-я]+ ([А-Я])[а-я]+", "$1 $2. $3.");
System.out.println(name); // Иванов И. И.
```

---

**PS.**

Круглые скобки тут создают группу символов. А `$<n>` позволяют получить группу по ее номеру

**PPS**

В `а-яА-Я` лучше включать отдельно букву `ёЁ`, например `[А-Яа-яёЁ]+` из-за того, что она не входит в диапазон тех символов.

Наглядный пример:

```
System.out.println((int)'а'); // 1072
System.out.println((int)'я'); // 1103
System.out.println((int)'ё'); // 1105
```

Как видите, `ё` не входит в диапазон символов от `а` до `я`

Comment: Спасибо! Подошло)

Comment: @МаксимФролов, тогда примите ответ :)